# How to get Unique record from this CAML Query?

Tags: javascript, caml-query

This query return duplicate record. I want to get only unique record. 
I want to fetch like my list contains 
User1,
User2,
User1
I want get record User1 and User2.

```
    var context = new SP.ClientContext();  
         var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Users');  
         var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();  
         caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Customer' /><Value Type='Text'>"+name+"</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>");  
         returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
         context.load(returnedItems);  
         //Run the query asynchronously, passing the functions to call when a response arrives  
         context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);


  function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) { 
         //Get an enumerator for the items in the list  
         var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Is "Users" list custom list ? Does your list have "allow unique values" for name column ?

Comment: List contains duplicate name i want to fetch only unique name record.

Comment: As you are using `<BeginsWith>` so duplicate is expected. Change it so `<Eq>` if you can.

Comment: Thanks for reply Atish but i check Customer name  in this customer name has multiple user with same name user i want to get unique record.Same issue for <Eq> i try it.

Comment: unique records based on what? you list has duplicate customer names so CAML will give you duplicates. So now you have to find them using different column. Another thing you can do is: remove duplicates from your list

Comment: According to me CAML query doesn't support duplicate check. What  you can do is get the user list and build an unique array of users after fetching from SPlist.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> `<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>`

to get first record from the result set.

Comment: No this is not work for me i want to fetch like my list contains User1,User2,User1 I want get record User1 and User2.